# input text restricting pattern 1 to 99 (only integers, no . or , allowed)

Tags: html, input, integer

I have the following problem. I have an input field of the type text and I want to only allow integers from 1 to 99, this manually added in the input text field. What am I doing wrong?

This is in html

```
<input maxlength="2" 
       class="increase-decrease-quantity" 
       type="text" pattern="([1-9]{1}[0-9])">
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Is this a html page?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 2):

The `pattern` attribute does not prevent the user from actually entering wrong values into the field. Upon submitting the form the input will be checked against the regex, though.

If you want the user to not be able to enter letters, dots, etc, you could attach a listener to your input element.

Comment: In addition, the `pattern` attribute used does not allow input consisting of a single digit. It should be corrected to `pattern="[1-9]?[0-9]">`.